# Azure web service cannot connect to database

Tags: azure

I have created a web service and a SQL database on Azure and I have deployed my Asp.net web app and upload my database on Azure SQL server. After that I created an connection string to connect my web app to database, but my web app cannot connect to database.

[image]

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? Have you configured Firewall rules appropriately?

Comment: In Firewall section "Allow access to Azure services" is ON. It just return timeout.

Comment: Can you use the portal to connect to the database manually using the credentials specified?

Comment: Yes, I used the portal and every thing about connection was OK.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had this problem, too. The cause of my problem is my publish settings.

Summary of my problem,
I used Visual Studio(VS) to publish my app service to azure with default publish settings, and even though I could access front-end contents, I couldn't access back-end services. For database operations, I used Entity Framework and migration.

For local machines, everything was fine, but on azure not.

Answer,
I simple uncheck "Execute Code First Migrations" checkbox in "Settings" step in publish modal window, and on azure everything was fine, but I faced another problem, no migration at all. To solve the migration problem, I added a small code in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    // For migration
    try
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
            new System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyWebApp.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext, MyWebApp.Migrations.Configuration>());
        var context = MyWebApp.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext.Create();
        context.Roles.Find("JustForDBMigrationKick");
        context.Dispose();
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        // Ooops, something went wrong
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix (the way I do it) is to use a Linked Resource to add a SQL Database database to your web site by using the Application Settings blade : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/

[image: https://acom.azurecomcdn.net/80C57D/cdn/mediahandler/docarticles/dpsmedia-prod/azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/20160816064407/configure01.png]

Comment: To add, it looks like the OP was trying to configure a Mobile > Data Connection. Also the view in the portal is somewhat different from the screenshot (at least from what I see), but there is still a Settings > Application Settings option further down in the vertical menu.